# OpenCL NDRange usage - Kernel only changes part of the output buffer

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a Kernel that I call with a 3-dimensional NDRange, but it only changes part of the output buffer.

Kernel:

```
__kernel void Kernel2(
 __global const float* K2BufIn,
 __global float* K2BufOut)
{

    int id0 = get_global_id(0);
    int id1 = get_global_id(1);
    int id2 = get_global_id(2);
    int gs0=get_global_size(0);
    int gs1=get_global_size(1);
    int gs2=get_global_size(2);
    int globalThreadNum = id0 + id1 * gs0 + id2 * gs0 * gs1;

    K2BufOut[globalThreadNum] = K2BufIn[globalThreadNum] * K2BufIn[globalThreadNum];

}
```

This is called as follows:

```
float pK2BufInData[24] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0};
float pK2BufOutData[24] = {};
int sizeK2BufIn = 24;
int sizeK2BufOut = 24;

K2BufIn = cl::Buffer(context_, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeK2BufIn);
K2BufOut = cl::Buffer(context_, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeK2BufOut);

commandQ_.enqueueWriteBuffer(K2BufIn, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeK2BufIn, pK2BufInData);

kernel_Kernel2_.setArg(0, K2BufIn);
kernel_Kernel2_.setArg(1, K2BufOut);


commandQ_.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_Kernel2_, cl::NULLRange, cl::NDRange(4,3,2));

commandQ_.enqueueReadBuffer(K2BufOut, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeK2BufOut, pK2BufOutData);
```

What I would expect is that pK2BufOutData then contains the squares of the input numbers.
Debugging however, gives me:

```
(gdb) p *pK2BufOutData@24
$17 = {0 <repeats 16 times>, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576}
```

Which means that the code only works for the last 8 entries. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in this thread: [Problem with get_global_id(1);](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/744339/cuda-programming-and-performance/problem-with-get_global_id-1-/post/4221408/#4221408)

It turns out the line

```
commandQ_.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_Kernel2_, cl::NULLRange, cl::NDRange(4,3,2));
```

has to be changed to

```
commandQ_.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_Kernel2_, cl::NDRange(), cl::NDRange(4,3,2));
```